# Adding Image To Worksheet Header/Footer - Office JS - Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins

I'm trying to insert an image into the header of an Excel worksheet programmatically from an Office JS taskpane.

I can load the image into the *worksheet* just fine, I can move it all over the sheet's range. I can also access the header and edit the *text* inside. But I can't find a way to get an image into the header.

I know from [this](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/adding-logo-or-image-to-header-footer) tutorial that it's possible in VBA by updating `sheet.PageSetup.LeftFooterPicture.Filename`, and I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938189/adding-picture-to-footer-of-a-word-document) answer that it's possible in Office JS for *Word* by accessing `footer.Shapes`, so I'm optimistic that it's possible, but I can't find any info on it.

Comment: We are doing a survey to understand the pain points of add-in’s developing experience. Would you mind to help fill this survey https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR5eAlIUFFQFHqE95qTMqQuVURVE4QkZPREoxOEk1TFEySDMyQTc0U0o0Ti4u ? It should take less than 5 minutes and will be supper helpful for us. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your question. However, currently the feature: insert an image into the header of an Excel worksheet from Office.js, is not supported. This feature is in our backlog 5328697.

Thanks,
Microsoft 365 Developer Platform team